# email id is not working from php to asp age

Tags: php, asp.net, forms

i am trying to send a emailid from php page to asp page...but its does not receive 
 by my server. i am using form get method..but if i add @ in my mail id..then    its     show error..other wise its ok.... its my php page coding

```
         <form action="Default.aspx" method="GET" name="frm" title="demo" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  Email<br/> <input type="text" name="email"/><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>

     </form>
```